# Accessing SignalR Hub in Web App from Windows Service

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I've created a SignalR hub and have it working within my web app. Now I'm trying to get a separate Windows service to send a message to that hub. Depending on what I use for the hub connection URL, I get 401 Unauthorized, or a SocketException. What am I missing to get the Windows service to be able to send a message to the hub?

Startup class in web app:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MmaWebClient.Startup))]
namespace MmaWebClient
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Hub class in web app:

```
[HubName("scannerHub")]
public class ScannerHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Script references in index.html:

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
```

JavaScript (that works) in my AngularJS controller:

```
    if (!$scope.state.hub) {
        $scope.state.hub = $.connection.scannerHub;
        $scope.state.hub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
            onSubIdOrCassetteIdEntered(scanText);
        }
        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                console.log('Connected to SignalR. Connection ID: ' + $.connection.scannerHub.connection.id +
                    '. URL: ' + $.connection.scannerHub.connection.baseUrl +$.connection.scannerHub.connection.appRelativeUrl);
            })
            .fail(function (response) {
                showInfoModal.show('Connection to SignalR Failed', 'This connection is necessary to read the ' +
                    'scans from the scanner. Response message: ' + response.message);
            });
    }
```

And, finally, in the Windows service:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoResetEvent scanReceivedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/MmaWebClient/signalr");
        //Make proxy to hub based on hub name on server
        var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("scannerHub");
        //Start connection

        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}",
                                  task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }

        }).Wait();


        myHub.On<string>("broadcastMessage", param => {
            Console.WriteLine("Scan received from server = [{0}]", param);
            scanReceivedEvent.Set();
        });

        string input = "";

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to send to hub or Q to quit.");

            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input.ToUpperInvariant() != "Q")
            {
                myHub.Invoke<string>("Send", input);
                scanReceivedEvent.WaitOne(1000);
            }

        } while (input.ToUpperInvariant() != "Q");

        connection.Stop();
    }
```

When I create the new hub connection in the above code, I've tried these three URLs without success:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/MmaWebClient/signalr");
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080");
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost");
```

First URL: 401 Unauthorized
Second URL: Socket Exception
Third URL: 404 Not Found

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost/MmaWebClient` ? For C# SignalR client I'm using the url without signalr/hubs part, and it works ok.

Comment: I get 401 Unauthorized when I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by setting the credentials on the connection (second line, below):

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/MmaWebClient");
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("scannerHub");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but here's an alternative method to map the SignalR endpoint. Hard to get the URL wrong with this one.

*ASP.NET Startup.cs*

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{    
    app.Map("/foo", map =>
    {
        //Specify according to your needs
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
           EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });

    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

*Client*

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/foo", useDefaultUrl: false);
var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("scannerHub");
```

Comment: I tried that and got a 404 Not Found. I had to comment the ConfigureAuth line because it wasn't available to me.

Comment: Did you run the web page with a custom port?